# Python list of dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this list of dict and I want to remove the duplicates based on name but at the same time choose on key type by this order [Polygone, LineString, Point]

```
dictionary = [{'firstName': 'Jabari', 'type':'Polygone'},{'firstName': 'Jabari', 'type':'LineString'},{'firstName': 'Jabari', 'type':'Point'},{'firstName': 'Jabari', 'type':'Polygone'},{'firstName': 'Bane', 'type':'LineString'},{'firstName': 'Bane', 'type':'Point'},{'firstName': 'Jack', 'type':'Point'}]
```

The result would be:

```
dictionary = [{'firstName': 'Jabari', 'type':'Polygone'},{'firstName': 'Bane', 'type':'LineString'},{'firstName': 'Jack', 'type':'Point'}]
```

I removed duplicate but I don't know how to get the second part working

```
done = set()
result = []
for d in dictionary:
    if d['firstName'] not in done:
        done.add(d['firstName']) 
        result.append(d)
print(result)
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything? What went wrong?

Comment: I've update what i did for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1--Use conditionals to filter to desired output

```
def filter_dict(input_dict):
  # place priorities on type
  accept = {'Polygone':3, 'LineString':2, 'Point':1}
  done = set()
  result = []
  for current in input_dict:
    if current['type'] in accept.keys():
      # Acceptable type
      if current['firstName'] not in done:
        # Not present and one of the acceptable types
        done.add(current['firstName']) 
        result.append(current)
      elif current['firstName'] in done:
        # Duplicate, check if higher priority
        for i in range(len(result)):
          previous = result[i]
          if result[i]['firstName'] == current['firstName'] and \
            accept[previous['type']] < accept[current['type']]:
            # Higher Priority with same name, so replace with current
            result[i] = current

  return result

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)


d1 = [{'firstName': 'Jabari', 'type':'Polygone'},
{'firstName': 'Jabari', 'type':'LineString'},
{'firstName': 'Jabari', 'type':'Point'},
{'firstName': 'Jabari', 'type':'Polygone'},
{'firstName': 'Bane', 'type':'LineString'},
{'firstName': 'Bane', 'type':'Point'},
{'firstName': 'Jack', 'type':'Point'}]

print('First Output')
pp.pprint(filter_dict(d1))

d2 = [{'firstName': 'Jabari', 'type':'Point'},
  {'firstName': 'Jabari', 'type':'LineString'},
  {'firstName': 'Jabari', 'type':'Polygone'},
  {'firstName': 'Bane', 'type':'LineString'},
  {'firstName': 'Bane', 'type':'Point'},
  {'firstName': 'Jack', 'type':'Point'},
  {'firstName': 'Jack', 'type':'Polygone'},
  {'firstName': 'Jack', 'type':'LineString'}] 

print('Second Output')
pp.pprint(filter_dict(d2))
```

Option 2--Use itertools

```
from itertools import groupby

def filter_itertools(input_dict):
  g = groupby(input_dict, lambda d: d['firstName'])
  accept = {'Polygone':3, 'LineString':2, 'Point':1}
  result = [max(v, key=lambda d: accept[d['type']]) for k, v in g]
  return result

print('First itertools')
pp.pprint(filter_itertools(d1))
print('Second itertools')
pp.pprint(filter_itertools(d2))
```

Output (Both options have the same result)

```
First Output
[   {'firstName': 'Jabari', 'type': 'Polygone'},
    {'firstName': 'Bane', 'type': 'LineString'},
    {'firstName': 'Jack', 'type': 'Point'}]
Second Output
[   {'firstName': 'Jabari', 'type': 'Polygone'},
    {'firstName': 'Bane', 'type': 'LineString'},
    {'firstName': 'Jack', 'type': 'Polygone'}]
First itertools
[   {'firstName': 'Jabari', 'type': 'Polygone'},
    {'firstName': 'Bane', 'type': 'LineString'},
    {'firstName': 'Jack', 'type': 'Point'}]
Second itertools
[   {'firstName': 'Jabari', 'type': 'Polygone'},
    {'firstName': 'Bane', 'type': 'LineString'},
    {'firstName': 'Jack', 'type': 'Polygone'}]
```

Comment: I believe the order of "accept" matters. So I would suggest replacing the set with a list i.e. replacing: accept=set(['Polygone', 'LineString', 'Point']) with accept=['Polygone', 'LineString', 'Point'].

Comment: @Ouss--I believe expression (d['type'] in accept) has the same truthiness regardless of accept being a list or set.  However, as a set, the performance is O(1), while for a list its O(n).  But, difference neglible in this case with only 3 elements.

Comment: @TarekTarek--not sure I understand your question.  My answer just adds a check for being an element of a list or set to your if condition.  Used set since that's faster for larger number of elements but doesn't matter in this case with three elements.

Comment: If the list was like these how can i have the same result? dict = [{'firstName': 'Jabari', 'type':'Point'},{'firstName': 'Jabari', 'type':'LineString'},{'firstName': 'Jabari', 'type':'Polygone'},{'firstName': 'Bane', 'type':'LineString'},{'firstName': 'Bane', 'type':'Point'},{'firstName': 'Jack', 'type':'Point'},{'firstName': 'Jack', 'type':'Polygone'},\ {'firstName': 'Jack', 'type':'LineString'}]

Comment: In the duplicate how to set the priority(like the polygon win over the line and point or if there is line and point in the duplicate then the line win over the point,etc)

Comment: @TarekTarek--I think I understand.

Comment: @TarekTarek--updated my answer.  Is this what you are expecting?

Comment: @DarrylG--the first output is good but the second output should have in his second line {'firstName': 'Bane', 'type':'LineString'} instead of {'firstName': 'Jack', 'type': 'Polygone'}

Comment: @TarekTarek--think I remedied the problem.  Forgot to insure you only replaced with higher priority if 'firstName' was the same.

Comment: By the way, instead of `sorted(..., reverse=True)[0]`, you can just use `max(...)`.

Comment: @iz_--good thinking, I like it.  Used it in my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# transform your list of dict into a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary) 

# create a new column called "score", assigning 1 for Polygone, 2 for LineString and 3 for Point
df['score'] = np.where(df['type'] == 'Polygone', 1, np.where(df['type'] == 'LineString', 2, np.where(df['type'] == 'Point', 3 , np.nan)))

# sort the dataframe by score
df.sort_values(by='score')

# drop rows with duplicated "firstName" 
# (by default the first duplicate is kept, hence the one with lowest score)
# remember: 1 -> Polygone, 2 -> LineString, 3 -> Point
df = df.drop_duplicates('firstName')

# drop the columns "score"
df = df.drop('score', axis=1)

# re-transform the dataframe into a list of dictionaries as it was at the beginning
new_list_dict = df.to_dict('records')

print(new_list_dict)
```

The most complicated part maybe is the `np.where` part.

Basically `np.where` takes a condition as first parameter ( `df['type'] == 'Polygone'`), then it returns the second parameter is true ( `1`), or it returns the third parameter if the condition isn't satisfied.

In this case what it returns if the condition isn't satisfied is another `np.where`, which this time checks if the "type" is "LineString". If it is "LineString", then it returns `2`.

Otherwise another `np.where` is called, which checks if the "type" corresponds to "Point" and returns 3 if it does.

If the "type" isn't any of the three, it returns `Nan`. But I think this shouldn't happen in your case .

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this by first building a dictionary recording every combination of `firstName` and its associated `types` in the dataset. Then I'd process that dictionary to create the output format I needed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from collections import defaultdict

# These are the names of the types, in descending order of importance
ORDER = ("Polygone", "LineString", "Point")

given = [
    {"firstName": "Jabari", "type": "Polygone"},
    {"firstName": "Jabari", "type": "LineString"},
    {"firstName": "Jabari", "type": "Point"},
    {"firstName": "Jabari", "type": "Polygone"},
    {"firstName": "Bane", "type": "LineString"},
    {"firstName": "Bane", "type": "Point"},
    {"firstName": "Jack", "type": "Point"},
]

expected = [
    {"firstName": "Jabari", "type": "Polygone"},
    {"firstName": "Bane", "type": "LineString"},
    {"firstName": "Jack", "type": "Point"},
]

# For each item, we're going to store all of the types of that item that we've seen. Making this a
# dict handles the dedupeing part for free! Making the dict's value a set means that we don't care
# how many entries we find for each item: even if there are 1,000,000, we'll at most be storing a
# three-item set.
found = defaultdict(set)

for item in given:
    # Each "type" will map to the number of its location in the ORDER tuple
    index = ORDER.index(item["type"])

    found[item["firstName"]].add(index)

output = []
for name, types in found.items():
    # Now, for each item in "found" dict, find its smallest type index
    lowest_index = sorted(types)[0]

    # Map that index back to its type name
    type_name = ORDER[lowest_index]

    # Add it to the results
    output.append({"firstName": name, "type": ORDER[lowest_index]})

assert output == expected
```